# how can I change the order of the strings in the data file by shellscript

Tags: shell

The data is saved in 'test_id.fileids' and it's aligned as shown below:

```
mdlr1/mdlr1-si1299
mdlr1/mdlr1-sa2
mdlr1/mdlr1-si1929
mhxl0/mhxl0-sx242
mhxl0/mhxl0-sa1
fcrz0/fcrz0-si2053
fcrz0/fcrz0-sx343
mgak0/mgak0-sx136
mjjm0/mjjm0-sx107
mjjm0/mjjm0-si1251

...
```

how could I change them to ?

```
mdlr1/si1299-mdlr1
mdlr1/sa2-mdlr1
mdlr1/si1929-mdlr1
mhxl0/sx242-mhxl0
mhxl0/sa1-mhxl0
fcrz0/si2053-fcrz0
fcrz0/sx343-fcrz0
mgak0/sx136-mgak0
mjjm0/sx107-mjjm0
mjjm0/si1251-mjjm0

...
```

Comment: What's the sort rule? It seems not a lexicographical order

Comment: Just change the order between the second and third part for each line. e.g. mdlr1/mdlr1-si1299  -->   mdlr1/si1299-mdlr1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example

```
echo "mdlr1/mdlr1-si1299" | awk -F'/' '{split($2,tmpArr,"-"); print $1"/" tmpArr[2]"-"tmpArr[1]}'
```

**output**

```
 mdlr1/si1299-mdlr1
```

You can skip the `echo ... |` and just use a filename after the awk cmd, AND redirect to a tmp file, and then move that tmp file back to your original file (OR you can skip the `&& mv ..` and just keep a new and old version of your file).

```
awk -F'/' '{split($2,tmpArr,"-"); print $1"/" tmpArr[2]"-"tmpArr[1]}' yourFile > FixedFile && mv FixedFile yourFile
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

Okey enjoy the following code:

```
paste -d / <(awk -F'/' {'print $1'} test_id.fileids )  <(awk  -F'/' {'print  $2'} test_id.fileids |awk -F'-' {'print $2 "-" $1'} )
```

Output is :

```
mdlr1/si1299-mdlr1
mdlr1/sa2-mdlr1
mdlr1/si1929-mdlr1
mhxl0/sx242-mhxl0
mhxl0/sa1-mhxl0
fcrz0/si2053-fcrz0
fcrz0/sx343-fcrz0
mgak0/sx136-mgak0
mjjm0/sx107-mjjm0
mjjm0/si1251-mjjm0
```

Then you can store to a file such as:

```
paste -d / <(awk -F'/' {'print $1'} test_id.fileids )  <(awk  -F'/' {'print  $2'} test_id.fileids |awk -F'-' {'print $2 "-" $1'} ) > output.txt
```